# Ant - Delete all folders with name?

Tags: jquery, bash, ant, build

In Ant, here's what I use to delete a folder with my build directory called "uncompressed":

```
<delete dir="${BUILD_DIR}/uncompressed"/>
```

...but how would I recursively delete all folders that have the name "uncompressed" in the build directory (including subfolders)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a resource collection within your delete task.

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true">
    <fileset dir="${BUILD_DIR}" includes="**/uncompressed/**" />
</delete>
```

More on that under:

- http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html

Include pattern documentation can be found here:

- http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below link.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html

```
<delete includeEmptyDirs="true">
  <fileset dir="root" includes="**/to_delete/"/>
</delete>
```

Try below also

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true">
    <fileset dir="${root}" defaultexcludes="false">
       <include name="**/*tmp*/**" />
    </fileset>
</delete>
```